# Secure a contact form from scratch in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, email

I am currently creating a website with Wordpress, I am creating my theme and I am not using jQuery. I need to introduce a simple contact form, which sends an email on submission and all plugins need jquery to work.

Is it safe to create a contact form that sends an email? Is there a risk of SQL injection since I do not query the database on submission?

I have very little security skill, any information or clarification will be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for example something like:

```
$name = "{$_POST['message_name']} {$_POST['message_lastname']}"; // I like to combine first and lastname in to 1 variable.

$email = $_POST['message_email'];
$website = $_POST['message_url'];
$message = $_POST['message_description'];

if ( ! filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) { 
 $response = form_validation_response( 'error', $email_invalid );
} else {
 if ( empty( $name ) || empty( $message) ) {
  $response = form_validation_response( 'error', $missing_content );
 }
}

// The most simple check you can do is make sre that the fields are NOT empty.
```

The form_validation_response method is a simple function which you can use to return error message:

```
$not_human       = "Human verification incorrect.";
$missing_content = "Please supply all information.";
$email_invalid   = "Email Address Invalid.";
$message_unsent  = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
$message_sent    = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";

function form_validation_response( $type, $message ) {
 $class = 'px-2 py-1 mb-6 rounded-md' // These are tailwind classes, but it could be bootstrap
 if ( $type == 'success' ) {
    $class .= "border border-green-800 text-green-700";
 } else {
    $class .= "border border-redish text-redish";
 }

 return "<div class='{$class}'>{$message}</div>";
}
```

The example above is used to validate the email, but you can also make sure that the fields are actually submitted, before even starting the validation process:

Comment: Thank you for these bases it is very useful! If I understand correctly, it is the filter_var () function which secures and verifies that the user only submits expected values. But without this function, what would be the risks? That the user is running PHP code on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not familiar with creating a "secure" php form I would advice you to use a plugin for this.

If your "allowed" to install plugins, then have a look "form plugins" like:

- WPForms (https://wpforms.com/)
- Gravity Forms (https://www.wpbeginner.com/refer/gravityforms/)
- Contact Form 7 (https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)

This is just a few of the form plugins that are available. Depending on your need/budget you should then make a decision which plugin fits the best (some are free,  freemium, premium etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). I am not authorized to use a plugin, I can fully invest myself in the creation of the form, what are the risks if it is not sufficiently secure? (if you know any documentations I would be very happy)

Comment: Hm in that case I would recommend to build a form, whenever it's submitted, to make sure that you validate the input fields (the $_POST data). 

I'll show a simple example in the next comment, 1 sec.